# How to launch a window on java(fx)?

Tags: javafx, fxml

I'm having an issue, I've put an exception around part of my code and it returns

> "Caught expection : 
>   /Users/delorszimi/Documents/Documents/Java%20CW/JavaFXbasics/bin/Main.fxml:8"

It seems there's a problem with the anchorPane section in my fxml file that's stopping it from launching. Most of my code is below...

```
package application;

import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.stage.Stage;
import javafx.scene.Parent;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;

public class Main extends Application {

static Stage window = new Stage();

@Override
public void start(Stage window) throws Exception {

    try{
    window.setTitle("Sprite Editor");

    BorderPane pane = new BorderPane();
    Scene sc = new Scene(pane,300,300);
    Parent content = FXMLLoader.load(getClass().getClassLoader().getResource("Main.fxml"));
    pane.setCenter(content);
    window.setScene(sc);
    window.show();
    window.setOnCloseRequest(e -> closeWindow());
    }
    catch(Exception e){
        System.err.println("Caught expection : " + e.getMessage());
    }


            }
private void closeWindow() {
    Boolean decision = ConfirmBox.display("Are you sure you want to exit?", "Title");
    if(decision)
    window.close();
}

public static void main(String[] args) {
    launch(args);
}
}
```

FXML file

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>

<?import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas?>
<?import javafx.scene.layout.AnchorPane?>



<AnchorPane prefHeight="432.0" prefWidth="498.0" 
 xmlns="http://javafx.com/javafx/8.0.141" xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml/1" 
fx:controller="MainController">
   <children>
  <Canvas fx:id="Canvas1" height="240.0" layoutX="81.0" layoutY="39.0" 
width="308.0" />
   </children>
</AnchorPane>
```

---

```
package application;

import javafx.event.ActionEvent;
import javafx.fxml.FXML;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.canvas.Canvas;
import javafx.scene.canvas.GraphicsContext;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ColorPicker;
import javafx.scene.layout.StackPane;
import javafx.scene.paint.Color;

public class MainController {


@FXML 
public void initialize(){




    Button botao = new Button("Browse Files");
    Button exit = new Button("Exit");
    exit.setOnAction(e -> System.exit(0));
    StackPane layout = new StackPane();
    layout.getChildren().addAll(botao,exit);

     final Canvas canvas1 = new Canvas(500,300);

        GraphicsContext gc = canvas1.getGraphicsContext2D();
        gc.setStroke(Color.BLACK);
        gc.setLineWidth(1);

        ColorPicker cp = new ColorPicker();
        layout.getChildren().addAll(canvas1,cp);
        Scene sc = new Scene(cp);

        sc.setOnMousePressed(e->{
            gc.beginPath();
            gc.lineTo(e.getSceneX(), e.getSceneY());
            gc.stroke();

        });

        sc.setOnMouseDragged(e->{
            gc.lineTo(e.getSceneX(), e.getSceneY());
            gc.stroke();

        });
    }


    public void size(){
    double width,height;

}


public void fileSelection(ActionEvent evento){




}

}
```

Comment: Not catching the exception would yield useful info, since you get the full stack trace instead of just the message as well as the exception types and causes of the exception, but I bet `FXMLLoader` is unable to find the controller class, since you did not provide the fully qualified name (`application.MainController`).

Comment: Hi Fabian thanks for your input, I've made the change and it still doesn't launch, any ideas on what could be the issue.

Comment: Please post the actual exception, preferably along with the stack trace.

Answer (score 0):

In FXML file you take a AnchorPane but in code section you create a borderpane instance, don't understand this part. And remove `getClassLoader()` and try once. I am not sure but you can check for once.